# Efficient RLE ideas for bit-wise data

Tags: compression, lossless-compression

One of my major projects is a display library for microcontrollers. As part of it I have a collection of fonts (bitmap) and icons (alpha channel).

Since resources (flash memory and RAM) are limited in microcontrollers I am looking at better ways of storing the data for these fonts and icons.

I am leaning towards using a separated-plane arrangement for the data (like ILBM on the Amiga used) - that is, instead of storing all the bits for each pixel together you store all the first bits for the entire image together, followed by the second bits, etc. That becomes more efficient for working with image depths that aren't a power-of-two (have you tried packing 3 bit data into an 8 bit data stream?).

I'd also then like to compress each of those bitplanes. RLE seems to be the most sensible. However, since I am now working with streams of bits, and not integer numbers, I am wondering what the best way of implementing the RLE would be.

I could stick to the traditional method of treating the bits in blocks of 8 and looking for repeated bytes (2 or more the same, replace with 2 the same followed by the count of how many in the run), but I can't see that being that great when it comes to the bit-wise data that would comprise one single bitplane. (Incidentally, ILBM uses a variety of this byte-wise method - treating the data purely as bytes and repeating them as necessary with "header" bytes defining how the next byte(s) are to be treated).

An alternative would be to use an alternating-bit-count method. That is, start assuming the bit is 0, and record the number of that bit in the run. Then switch to 1 and record the number of 1 bits in the run. Then switch back to 0 again and record the number of bits. Etc.

Again, great if you have long runs of the same bit, but as soon as you get a rapid alternation of bits you end up with a massive increase in space taken up (8 bits, say `01010101`, could end up as 8 bytes of `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`).

The main caveat for anything here is that it has to be efficient - both in CPU to decompress it, and in memory to hold any working buffers while it decompresses. That's why I am thinking RLE rather than any of the other methods.

So I guess I'm looking for the ideas that I have missed. What would be the best implementation for compressing a stream of single bits and representing that compressed data in a byte-centric system?

---

An example glyph (decimal):

```
00 00 02 14 03 00 00 00
00 00 09 13 10 00 00 00
00 00 13 05 13 00 00 00
00 05 12 00 12 06 00 00
00 11 15 15 15 11 00 00
00 14 02 00 01 14 00 00
08 12 00 00 00 12 08 00
11 07 00 00 00 07 12 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Bitplanes 0-3 would, therefore, be

```
   0            1            2            3
00001000     00111000     00010000     00010000
00111000     00001000     00010000     00111000
00111000     00000000     00111000     00101000
01000000     00000100     01101100     00101000
01111100     01111100     00111000     01111100
00001000     01100100     01000100     01000100
00000000     00000000     01000100     11000110   
11000100     11000100     01000110     10000010
00000000     00000000     00000000     00000000
00000000     00000000     00000000     00000000
```

However a glyph this size I would be unlikely to even attempt to compress. It's small enough to be pointless. However, it illustrates the layering of the bitplanes and how the bitstreams would look in relation to the original data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the compression of bitmap images has been the subject of research for decades, so you could just use the result of that, which is JBIG2. You can google for open source JBIG2 code.

Comment: JBIG2 looks efficient when you have repeated patterns of the same blocks of data (e.g., characters on a page) and is optimised for a single 1-bit bitmap. With a multi-bitplane image you don't tend to get those repeated patterns so much, especially when the image is of a single glyph in a font, or an icon, for example. We're talking bitplanes of maybe a couple of thousand pixels here (48x48 would be 2304 bits per bitplane). I know it doesn't sound a lot, but when you have a few hundred of them, and only a couple of hundred kB of storage, size matters.

Comment: Breaking a grayscale image into planes is exactly how JBIG2 is used. It will very likely perform better on your data than anything you try cook up in a short time.